# Cannot compile a basic SDL tutorial with C++ and visual studio 2010 express - SDL.h not found

Tags: c++, graphics, sdl

The file SDL.h is in C:/user/desktop/sdl-version/include/SDL.h (where SDL.h is the file not a new folder) and I have set up my property pages to include C:/user/desktop/sdl-version/include. However, when I compile it says SDL.h cannot be found. What is the issue?

Screen cap of the properties page:

[image http://imageshack.us/a/img16/53/propsr.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img16/53/propsr.png)

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of your property pages?

Comment: I just added it. Here it is again though: http://puu.sh/1llUA

Comment: When you click that link, can you see anything?  I can't.  I get a file with 0 bytes.

Comment: Sorry. Try this: http://imageshack.us/a/img16/53/propsr.png

Comment: Should there be quotes around the include directory path?  What happens if you remove them?

Comment: It works of course. Thank you so much! Go ahead and put up an answer so I can credit you.

Comment: If I remember right, those screens do allow quotes.  But, they're unnecessary here, since there's no spaces, etc.  Also, I don't remember whether you need to escape backslashes when you use quotes in the property editor.. might be worth looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotation marks around the include directory path.